# How to Return an Array from a function in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I'm new to C++ and am more used to Python. I have found posts answering this question, but I haven't been able to modify what I've found to work in my code. The goal of my function is simple, I want it to give me an array with x, y, and z coordinates where I give it polar coordinates. Here's what I have that isn't working:

```
double coordinate_finder(double coordinates[], double radius)
{
    double x = radius * sin(radians(90 - coordinates[0])) * cos(radians(coordinates[1]));
    double y = radius * sin(radians(90 - coordinates[0])) * sin(radians(coordinates[1]));
    double z = radius * cos(radians(90 - coordinates[0]));

    double XYZ[] = { x,y,z };
    return XYZ;

}
```

I feel like what I want it to do reads pretty easily but I'd like it to return XYZ when the function is called later in the code. By the way `radians()` is a function I made which converts degrees to radians.

Comment: Use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.

Comment: you should look into the concept of pointer, if you want to do in the c way

Comment: use a `point` struct with x, y, and z members :/

Comment: You can just overwrite the three values in `coordinates` if you want. But make sure to make internal copies if necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't return a C-style array as-is, but you can return a pointer to a dynamically allocated array, eg:

```
double* coordinate_finder(double coordinates[], double radius)
{
    ...

    double *XYZ = new double[3];
    XYZ[0] = x;
    XYZ[1] = y;
    XYZ[2] = z;

    return XYZ;
}
```

And then the caller will have to free it:

```
double* xyz = coordinate_finder(...);
...
delete[] xyz;
```

This can be made safer for the caller using `std::unique_ptr`:

```
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<double[]> coordinate_finder(double coordinates[], double radius)
{
    ...

    auto XYZ = std::make_unique<double[]>(3);
    XYZ[0] = x;
    XYZ[1] = y;
    XYZ[2] = z;

    return XYZ;
}
```

Or `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<double> coordinate_finder(double coordinates[], double radius)
{
    ...

    std::vector<double> XYZ(3);
    XYZ[0] = x;
    XYZ[1] = y;
    XYZ[2] = z;

    return XYZ;
}
```

Or a `static` variable (or `thread_local`, if multi-threading is a factor):

```
double* coordinate_finder(double coordinates[], double radius)
{
    static double XYZ[3];
    // thread_local double XYZ[3];

    ...

    XYZ[0] = x;
    XYZ[1] = y;
    XYZ[2] = z;

    return XYZ;
}
```

However, it would be better to simply return a `std::array` instead:

```
#include <array>

std::array<double,3> coordinate_finder(double coordinates[], double radius)
{
    ...
    std::array<double,3> XYZ = { x,y,z };
    return XYZ;
}
```

Or, a `std::tuple`:

```
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<double,double,double> coordinate_finder(double coordinates[], double radius)
{
    ...
    std::tuple<double,double,double> XYZ{ x,y,z };
    return XYZ;
}
```

Or, a custom `struct`/`class`:

```
struct xyz
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};

xyz coordinate_finder(double coordinates[], double radius)
{
    ...
    xyz XYZ{ x,y,z };
    return XYZ;
}
```

Comment: You can return a C-style array that is malloc'ed by the function. You need to free it later. (But passing it as an argument is even simpler.)

Comment: May also want to include a `vector<double>` example, mentioning copy elision, as that'll be "cheap" creation as well.  And/or `std::move` and how that would work.